# Homology of a closed $3$-manifold with balls removed

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

Let $M^3$ be a closed, connected and orientable smooth $3$-manifold and let $\mathring{M}$ denote the manifold $M$ with $n$ disjoint open balls $B_1, \dots, B_n$ removed. I am trying to compute $H_2(\mathring{M})$ in terms of $H_2(M)$, with the assumption that $H_2(M)$ is abelian free (everything with integer coefficients).

What I've done so far: by Mayer-Vietoris with $U = B_1' \cup \cdots \cup B_n'$ a collection of  slightly larger balls ($B_i \subset B_i'$) and $V = M \setminus (B_1 \cup \cdots B_n)$, we have a long exact sequence in homology

$$0 \to H_3(M) \cong \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{j}{\to} H_2(U \cap V) \cong \mathbb{Z}^n \stackrel{f}{\to} H_2(\mathring{M}) \stackrel{g}{\to} H_2(M) \to 0$$

By the comment made in [this previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3939401/exact-sequence-of-4-abelian-groups-3-of-them-being-free/3939409#3939409), it follows that $H_2(\mathring{M}) \cong H_2(M) \oplus \operatorname{coker}(j)$. Can we compute $\operatorname{coker}(j)$ in this case?

My guess is that $\operatorname{Im}(j)$ is generated by the element $(1, \dots, 1) \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, but I am not sure of this.